# How to suppress logger output when using <MSBuild ...> task?

Tags: msbuild

I need to run an external MSBuild thread from inside another MSBuild project. What I need to do is to pass the /noconsolelogger to the task . How can I do this, please help!

Answer (score 2):

foo.csproj

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAll" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="BuildAll">
        <Message Text="foo"/>
        <Exec Command="MSBuild.exe bar.csproj /noconsolelogger"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

bar.csproj

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAll" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="BuildAll">
        <Message Text="bar"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Output contains the message 'foo', but not 'bar'.

Comment: Thanks mhanney. I understand your suggestion is to use <Exec ...> instead of <MSBuild ...> directly. +1 vote for you but it would be greater to have an option for <MSBuild...>. Using <Exec...> task is quite annoying when defining properties.

Comment: I understand the annoyance of not being able to use <MSBuild ..> directly. Thanks for the +1.